# How do I open a manual file not located in the man directory?

Tags: bash, shell, sh, manpage

I would like to open a file `myscript.1.gz` that is not located at `/usr/share/man/man1`.

Comment: `man` varies across platforms, and you don't say which you are using.  Do a `man man` and look for a search path option.  Most versions will support the environment variable `MANPATH` which can be set in the same way as `PATH` and is used for a directory search.

Comment: Do you know where the file is? `man /path/to/myscript.1.gz` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `-l` (`--local-file`) option:

```
man -l myscript.1.gz
```

From `man man`:

> -l, --local-file
>
> Activate  `local'  mode.   Format  and display local manual files instead of searching through the system's manual collection.  Each manual page argument will be interpreted as an nroff
>                 source file in the correct format.  No cat file is produced.  If '-' is listed as one of the arguments, input will be taken from stdin.  When this option is not used, and man  fails  to
>                 find the page required, before displaying the error message, it attempts to act as if this option was supplied, using the name as a filename and looking for an exact match.

Comment: The `-l` option is not available on all platforms.  The only option in the POSIX standard is `-k`.

Comment: @cdarke The question is about loading a (custom) `man` page that is not in default man locations, and `MANPATH`, its not about searching something in the man page.

Comment: @heemay1:  yes, but the only option in POSIX is `-k`, which is no use in this context.  The point is that `-l` is non-standard.  It obviously works for the OP, but might not be available on other platforms (OS X, for example).